# Codeigniter route : how to show name in url instead of id number

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I need some help with url in codeigniter..

when I click on Details for a particular item the url is like this...
http://localhost/testproject/index.php/Item/details/2

is it possible to display like this?
http://localhost/testproject/index.php/Item/samsung-galaxy-s7

results are coming from the database. say my database look like this...

```
item_id       Item_name
------------------------

1             Nokia Lumia 5

2             samsung galaxy s7
```

My controller "Item", and function "details"

```
 public function details($item_id=0) 


    $data['itm_details']=$this->Item_model->getDetails($item_id);
    $data['view_page']='item/details_page';
    $this->load->view('homepage', $data);
```

Comment: come on, it's all written here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to click a url then change it after but One thing you can do is to pass the item name at the url then urldecode the given string.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function details($item_name=NULL){
        $item_name = urldecode($item_name);
        $data['itm_details']=$this->Item_model->getDetails($item_name);
        $data['view_page']='item/details_page';
        $this->load->view('homepage', $data);
}
```

Just an example

```
  function temp(){
    echo "<a href='".site_url('controller/temp_redirect/this sample_-url')."'>Click Me</a>";
  }

  function temp_redirect($url){
    echo urldecode($url);
  }
```